# Showing the same comboBox in two forms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I couldn't find anything similar to this, I have a combo box in the main window form and I want to pass the same combo box to another form and change it values there so it will change in the main window accordingly.

I am new to C# apologies for ignorance, I've tried the following:

**In main window:**

```
private void companiesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModifyCompanies childForm = new ModifyCompanies(this);
    childForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

**In the second form:**
I've built a constructor and thought it would work but the items don't display even if it's the same comboBox.

```
public ModifyCompanies(MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1 = mainWindow.companyComboBox;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass `ComboBox` between forms, but you may want to share a single data source between forms and use it as data source of combo boxes on those forms.

Comment: @RezaAghaei But why isn't it working if it's the same comboBox?

Comment: `comboBox1 = mainWindow.companyComboBox;` it's an statement which just says the variable `comboBox1` points to a combo box on another form.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Oh, so how can I share data then?

Comment: You could store data on a `list`, `database`, etc and just call data when needed.

Comment: The data store can be database, or it can be a `DataTable` or a `List<T>` or `BindingList<T>`.  If you are using a database, then in your second form you can add items to db, then in first form reload data to show them in combo box. If you are using in-memory data sources just for experiment and you don;t want to store them, you can create the data source in first form and when you want to change it, pass it to second form and since it's reference type, the change which you made on it will be visible in first form as well. In a real scenario you need to store data permanently e.g. in db.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Should one use database, if the amount of data to store is small?

Comment: It depends to your requirements. You need a permanent data store in a real application. It can be a database, a settings file, an xml file, and so on. A `DataSet/DataTable` can be simply saved to disk in an xml file and you can simply load it from disk again, so it would be a good storage for some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Passing controls to different forms may be a bad idea, I suggest sharing data between forms, something like the following sample :

```
public class SharedData
{
    public List<string> TestData { get; set; } 

    public SharedData()
    {
        TestData = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

And in your program class :

```
class Program
{
    public static SharedData Shared {get; set;}

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Shared = new SharedData();

        Shared.TestData.Add("test1");
        Shared.TestData.Add("test2");
        Shared.TestData.Add("test3");

        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

And inside the form it would be something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = Program.Shared.TestData;
    }
}
```

Other form will be the same and you can manipulate the data from the two forms and the data will be updated for both.

Hope this is useful.